# Multi-switch configuration with double uplink

Tags: redundancy

We want to configure our new network with 2 switches, redundantly, so if one of the uplinks goes down, or one of the switches dies, the network keeps on going..

We have the following setup:

(Switches are 2x Dell Networking N1524)

```
"public" VLAN configured on port 10-24 on every switch
1x Uplink connected to SW01-p24
1x Uplink connected to SW02-p24
cross-cable connected from SW01-p23 to SW01-p23
rapid-STP enabled on both switches
servers connected with an equal amount of cables to both switches
```

Do we need anything else for the network to be redundant this way? Any additional configuration?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is not gonna work that way unless you have stacked switches and ether channel/bundle or VPC configured on both switches to servers. Which not all switches support. Server usually don't take part in STP election. If you enable server to take part of STP election than you would have redundant links but at same time only 1 link would work and another would be in blocking state.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

We need to know more about the host configuration.  If you have some sort of active/passive NIC-teaming setup that can detect a failure then this configuration can work.  There are various options in both (modern) Windows and Linux to accomplish this, as well as a number of mechanisms to detect failures.  The upshot, though, is that a single MAC/IP address will normally show up on the primary NIC and that in the event of a failure both will be transferred to the standby.

If you had switches that could support MLAG or stacking you could provision the two NIC's as a single logical link.  This has the advantage of faster failover and load-sharing but I don't think the switches listed would support such a setup.